# Why my coinbase apikey always set to disabled by default?

Tags: coinbase-api

I'm trying to explore the API environment of coinbase. So for the very first time I accidentally set all of the scopes. Then I removed it and I created again.

Now every time I create a new key it will always put to `disabled` state by default. I keep getting this everytime there is a `update` `write` on the scope. The `read` scope seems to work for most of them (leaving trading related scopes) but not for `transactions` related scopes for both `read` and `write`.

Is there any particular reason why this is happening on my account? It's not verified btw, but that doesn't stop me from using it. Cause I only need a few basic scopes like reading my accounts addresses and transferring funds to another coinbase user something like that. I will not use this for trading.

Any help would be gladly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

It's for security purposes; according to the response email I also got from coinbase.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By the way it will *only* remain disabled for the next 48 hours for protection purposes. The solution is just to wait for 48 hours and then do all the stuff you want to do.